# SQLite Insert command in Python script Doesn't work on web

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to use an SQLite insert operation in a python script, it works when I execute it manually on the command line but when I try to access it on the web it won't insert it in the database. Here is my function:

```
def insertdb(unique_id,number_of_days):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        print "Opened database successfully";
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO IDENT (ID_NUM,DAYS_LEFT) VALUES (?,?)",(unique_id,number_of_days));
        conn.commit()
        print "Records created successfully";
        conn.close()
```

When it is executed on the web, it only shows the output "Opened database successfully" but does not seem to insert the value into the database. What am I missing? Is this a server configuration issue? I have checked the database permissions on writing and they are correctly set.

Comment: sqlite writes temporary journal files. The directory where your datab ase is located needs to have write access by your web server. Does it?

Comment: Do you know where I would go about changing this?

Comment: Normally the containing directory needs to have read/write/execute permissions for the webserver user (or group). e.g: If you're webserver user/group is apache/apache the following should fix this: ``chmod 775 /path/to/db/dir`` and ``chown apache:apache /path/to/db/dir``

Comment: Do you have any idea what the current working directory is when running in your unspecified web environment? If not, why are you using `database.db` without a full path? If so, what is it, and what are the owner and mode on it?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged `mysql` when you're trying to use `sqlite`?

Comment: Also, you don't need semicolons at the end of lines in Python, and shouldn't put them there. At best it's useless visual noise that will distract anyone reading the code; at worst it can be confusing in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you're trying to create or open a database named `database.db` in whatever happens to be the current working directory, and one of the following is true:

- The database exists and you don't have permission to write to it. So, everything works until you try to do something that requires write access (like `commit`ing an `INSERT`).
- The database exists, and you have permission to write to it, but you don't have permission to create new files in the directory. So, everything works until sqlite needs to create a temporary file (which it almost always will for `execute`-ing an `INSERT`).

Meanwhile, you don't mention what web server/container/etc. you're using, but apparently you have it configured to just swallow all errors silently, which is a really, really bad idea for any debugging. Configure it to report the errors in some way. Otherwise, you will *never* figure out what's going on with anything that goes wrong.

If you don't have control over the server configuration, you can at least wrap all your code in a `try`/`except` and manually log exceptions to some file you have write access to (ideally via the `logging` module, or just `open` and `write` if worst comes to worst).

Or, you can just do that with dumb `print` statements, as you're already doing:

```
def insertdb(unique_id,number_of_days):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        print "Opened database successfully";
        try:
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO IDENT (ID_NUM,DAYS_LEFT) VALUES (?,?)",(unique_id,number_of_days));
            conn.commit()
            print "Records created successfully";
        except Exception as e:
            print e # or, better, traceback.print_exc()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Awesome, you are correct it seems that I don't have the correct permissions to do an INSERT operation on the database via the web. Unsure how to go about doing that but at least I know what is wrong, and that's half the battle.

Comment: @RayY: I explained where to start looking in my answer and in my comments, along with James Mills's comments. What is the current working directory where `database.db` lives? What user does the web server run as? What's the ownership and permissions of `database.db` and of the directory it lives in? If the web-server user has a shell, it may help to login as that user and run your script directly in the command-line Python interpreter. And if you need more help on permissions stuff, ask at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).